# Multiple file upload from android webview (Kitkat and lower android versions)

Tags: java, android, webview, filechooser, webchromeclient

In my app, I am using webview to render a webpage from which I need to upload multiple files to the server. OnShowFileChooser() (for lollipop and upper versions) is working fine but onOpenFileChooser() (for other lower android versions). OnshowFileChooser() method not working if I pass an Uri array(Uri[]) to its onValueCallback(). It throws the classCastException. Below is my code which i have used for performing the required opertation. I need a solution to upload multiple file using webview which will work for all android versions.

```
public class ChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

    // For Android 5.0
    public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView view, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePath, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
        // Double check that we don't have any existing callbacks
        if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
            mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
        }
        mFilePathCallback = filePath;

        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
            }

            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            } else {
                takePictureIntent = null;
            }
        }

        Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        contentSelectionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        contentSelectionIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
        contentSelectionIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");

        Intent[] intentArray;
        if (takePictureIntent != null) {
            intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
        } else {
            intentArray = new Intent[0];
        }

        Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);

        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);

        return true;

    }


    //openFileChooser for other Android versions
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri[]> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {

        openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
    }

    // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri[]> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {

        mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
        // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
        // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard

        File imageStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                , "AndroidExampleFolder");

        if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
            // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
            imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
        }

        // Create camera captured image file path and name
        File file = new File(
                imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_"
                        + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
                        + ".jpg");

        mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);

        // Camera capture image intent
        final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        i.setType("image/*");

        // Create file chooser intent
        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser");

        // Set camera intent to file chooser
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Parcelable[]{captureIntent});

        // On select image call onActivityResult method of activity
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);


    }

    // openFileChooser for Android < 3.0
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri[]> uploadMsg) {
        openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
    }


}
```

> This is the onActivityResult code

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

        if (requestCode != INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE || mFilePathCallback == null) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            return;
        }

        Uri[] results = null;


        // Check that the response is a good one
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data == null) {
                // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                }
            } else {
                if (data.getData() != null) {

                    String dataString = data.getDataString();
                    if (dataString != null) {
                        // results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                        // Will return "image:x*"
                        String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(Uri.parse(dataString.replace("%3A", ":")));

                        // Split at colon, use second item in the array
                        String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];

                        String type = wholeID.split(":")[0];


                        String[] column = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                        // where id is equal to
                        String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

                        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().
                                query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                        column, sel, new String[]{id}, null);

                        String filePath = "";

                        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);

                        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse("file:" + filePath)};
                        }

                        cursor.close();
                    }
                } else {
                    if (data.getClipData() != null) {

                        ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();
                        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                        results = new Uri[clipData.getItemCount()];
                        for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
                            ClipData.Item image = clipData.getItemAt(i);
                            Uri uri = image.getUri();

                            // Will return "image:x*"
                            String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);

                            // Split at colon, use second item in the array
                            String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];

                            String type = wholeID.split(":")[0];
                            String contentUri;
                            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA;
                            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA;
                            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA;
                            }

                            String[] column = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                            // where id is equal to
                            String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

                            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().
                                    query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                            column, sel, new String[]{id}, null);

                            String filePath = "";

                            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);

                            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                                filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                            }

                            cursor.close();
                            results[i] = Uri.parse("file:" + filePath);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
        mFilePathCallback = null;

    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        if (requestCode != FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE || mUploadMessage == null) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            return;
        }

        if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {

            if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
                return;

            }

            Uri result[] = null;

            try {
                if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {

                    result = null;

                } else {
                    if (data.getData() != null)
                        result[0] = data.getData();
                    else {
                        if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                            result = new Uri[data.getClipData().getItemCount()];
                            for (int i = 0; i < data.getClipData().getItemCount(); i++) {
                                result[i] = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
                            }
                        } else {
                            result = null;
                        }
                    }
                    // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                    //result = data == null ? mCapturedImageURI : data.getData();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :" + e,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;

        }
    }

    return;
}
```

[this is the Error report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6LDo.png)